# converting a normal list into a nested one using a condition

Tags: python

I want to convert a normal list(main_list) into a nested one(ans_list) but I don't know how.

```
main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ans_list = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: What's the condition then? Every n-th member? How did you try to do it?

Comment: `it=iter(main_list); list(zip(*zip(it, it, it)))` from what I understood.

Comment: @FabioCraigWimmerFlorey, yes you're right. I mean every n-th number.

Comment: @Ch3steR, Thank you for your reply. It works indeed. A question, what if I want to have every 100th member? Do I have to write "it" variable 100 times?

Comment: @Ali No, it was just a fun way to do it. I had the same answer user2390182 posted he was quicker than me to post. Though you could do this, `list(zip(*zip(*[it]*N)))`, let `N` be any number. This is not a pythonic way to do it, just me abusing the language. :)

Comment: Thank you @user2390182 very much for your helpful answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR you can golf it even more: `[*zip(*zip(*[iter(main_list)]*n))]`. But I can't adjust it to create lists instead of tuples without resorting to list comprehension!

Comment: @FabioCraigWimmerFlorey We could use `map`, `[*map(list, zip(*zip(*[iter(main_list)]*n)))]` something like this.

Comment: @Ch3steR I tried `map` but I kept inverting the `*`! I need way more study and coffee! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) over appropriate [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
n = 3
ans_list = [main_list[i::n] for i in range(n)]
# [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: This is the right answer.
To the commenters: why using libraries, such as numpy, when you can do it easily?

Answer (score 1):

if you are open to using NumPy and there are no other conditions other than how many rows you want to split in to then try this

```
import numpy as np    
np.array(main_list).reshape(-1,3).tolist()
```